# Convert HTML+CSS+js page to similar excel file

Tags: java, gwt

I need to convert some **html+css+js** file to **excel** file, which should be *generated* by request from server side. I look at [How to Export Web page to Excel](http://www.quicklyjava.com/export-web-page-to-excel/), but my file generate table with googlechart.js (no table tag at all). Nonetheless, that is a good direction I think.

Additionaly, I look at ApachePOI and Jexel, but I don't understand them well.

---

So, my question is: Does anybody know how to convert HTML+CSS+js page to Excel file from Java? Is it really possible?

P.S. I've already converted that html+css+js page to pdf format, so it's good to have same for excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting generic html to excel, what you can do is export data to excel. If your page is generated by a Java server then ApachePOI is quite a standard tool to do this, so you're on good track. Since excel is tabular you should think about how to collect my data in a tabular fashion and transform that data to ApachePOI representation so you can generate an excel end send it to the client.

You can find nice examples here:
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/examples.html